# need to replace end of column with a character if it does not already exist

Tags: sed, awk

I am trying to use `awk` but can use anything else that will work

lets say i have a file with these lines

```
ewhueh wnlknlweknlnw/ qwejmdpdhhd 47578
enhkine enoekjohnkjiof elkjehbjuwekjuk 88989
ehnjkine efjlwkjflkjw/ ie3hjfihie 73746
ehneihe efhehjlkijehfl ekljekfjl 8438477
```

but i want all lines to end with the forward slash like this

```
ewhueh wnlknlweknlnw/ qwejmdpdhhd 47578
enhkine enoekjohnkjiof/ elkjehbjuwekjuk 88989
ehnjkine efjlwkjflkjw/ ie3hjfihie 73746
ehneihe efhehjlkijehfl/ ekljekfjl 8438477
```

How do i do this?

I tried this but got a bad result

`awk '{sub(/.$/, "/", $2)} 1'`

but got this

```
ewhueh wnlknlweknlnw/ qwejmdpdhhd 47578
enhkine enoekjohnkjio/ elkjehbjuwekjuk 88989
ehnjkine efjlwkjflkjw/ ie3hjfihie 73746
ehneihe efhehjlkijehf/ ekljekfjl 8438477
```

notice it took off the previous last character of the lines, and i do NOT want that

So how do i achieve this result?

```
ewhueh wnlknlweknlnw/ qwejmdpdhhd 47578
enhkine enoekjohnkjiof/ elkjehbjuwekjuk 88989
ehnjkine efjlwkjflkjw/ ie3hjfihie 73746
ehneihe efhehjlkijehfl/ ekljekfjl 8438477
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With awk:

```
awk '$2 !~ /\/$/ {$2 = $2 "/"}; 1' file
```

Comment: thanks alot..i have another question related http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/236128/awk-regex-for-apache-rewriterule

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Let's suppose the filename in question is foo.txt, so what you want can be accomplished with `sed` just like this:

```
sed 's/$/\//' foo.txt > aux && mv aux foo.txt
```