# Reformatting Apache RewriteRule

Tags: text-processing, apache-httpd, rewrite

I have these variant of urls

```
RewriteRule ^/trendy/the-reason-for-example/? http://www.example.com/trendy/the-reason [NC, L, R=301]
RewriteRule ^/lol/2015/10..._for-example http://www.example.com/lol/the-reason [NC, L, R=301]
RewriteRule ^/sports/this-one***-as-well/ http://www.example.com/sports/this-one [NC, L, R=301]
RewriteRule ^/buzz/the-#reason-for-buzz http://www.example.com/buzz/buzz-sells [NC, L, R=301]
RewriteRule ^/omg/ what-the-hell http://www.example.com/omg/wthell [NC, L, R=301]
RewriteRule ^/hash/HELL-YEAH http://www.example.com/hash/oh-yes [NC, L, R=301]
RewriteRule ^/celeb/he-did-it! http://www.example.com/celeb/we-believe [NC, L, R=301]
```

and I want to edit them using awk (sed or any other tool) to help edit these variant of URLs so it passes apache's rewriterule config test

Notice the characters like (*), (.), (#), (!) and even the space on the 5th line
How do I edit these set of lines so that everything looks correct to be deployed to apache and pass apache config test `httpd -t`?

EDIT: v1

Here is something that I am looking for that will pass apache's test

```
RewriteRule ^/trendy/the-reason-for-example/? http://www.example.com/trendy/the-reason [NC, L, R=301]
RewriteRule ^/lol/2015/10\.\.\._for-example http://www.example.com/lol/the-reason [NC, L, R=301]
RewriteRule ^/sports/this-one\*\*\*-as-well/ http://www.example.com/sports/this-one [NC, L, R=301]
RewriteRule ^/buzz/the-\#reason-for-buzz http://www.example.com/buzz/buzz-sells [NC, L, R=301]
RewriteRule ^/omg/\ what-the-hell http://www.example.com/omg/wthell [NC, L, R=301]
RewriteRule ^/hash/HELL-YEAH http://www.example.com/hash/oh-yes [NC, L, R=301]
RewriteRule ^/celeb/he-did-it\! http://www.example.com/celeb/we-believe [NC, L, R=301]
```

NOTE: please note line 5 had space and I had to escape the space. So there needs to be a way to detect is there is space in column 2 then escape it -- something along that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know much about Apache rules, so this is probably overkill. However, if too much escaping is not a problem, you can use:

```
$ perl -ne 'print quotemeta()' file
RewriteRule\ \^\/trendy\/the\-reason\-for\-example\ http\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/trendy\/the\-reason\ \[NC\,\ L\,\ R\=301\]\
RewriteRule\ \^\/lol\/2015\/10\.\.\._for\-example\ http\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/lol\/the\-reason\ \[NC\,\ L\,\ R\=301\]\
RewriteRule\ \^\/sports\/this\-one\*\*\*\-as\-well\ http\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/sports\/this\-one\ \[NC\,\ L\,\ R\=301\]\
RewriteRule\ \^\/buzz\/the\-\#reason\-for\-buzz\ http\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/buzz\/buzz\-sells\ \[NC\,\ L\,\ R\=301\]\
RewriteRule\ \^\/omg\/\ what\-the\-hell\ http\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/omg\/wthell\ \[NC\,\ L\,\ R\=301\]\
RewriteRule\ \^\/hash\/HELL\-YEAH\ http\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/hash\/oh\-yes\ \[NC\,\ L\,\ R\=301\]\
RewriteRule\ \^\/celeb\/he\-did\-it\!\ http\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/celeb\/we\-believe\ \[NC\,\ L\,\ R\=301\]\
```

Otherwise, to escape only the specific characters you mentioned, use:

```
$ sed 's#[*.#!]#\\&#g' file
RewriteRule\ ^/trendy/the-reason-for-example\ http://www\.example\.com/trendy/the-reason\ [NC,\ L,\ R=301]
RewriteRule\ ^/lol/2015/10\.\.\._for-example\ http://www\.example\.com/lol/the-reason\ [NC,\ L,\ R=301]
RewriteRule\ ^/sports/this-one\*\*\*-as-well\ http://www\.example\.com/sports/this-one\ [NC,\ L,\ R=301]
RewriteRule\ ^/buzz/the-\#reason-for-buzz\ http://www\.example\.com/buzz/buzz-sells\ [NC,\ L,\ R=301]
RewriteRule\ ^/omg/\ what-the-hell\ http://www\.example\.com/omg/wthell\ [NC,\ L,\ R=301]
RewriteRule\ ^/hash/HELL-YEAH\ http://www\.example\.com/hash/oh-yes\ [NC,\ L,\ R=301]
RewriteRule\ ^/celeb/he-did-it\!\ http://www\.example\.com/celeb/we-believe\ [NC,\ L,\ R=301]
```

To do the same but only on the second field, use:

```
$ perl -lne '/(.+\^)(.*)( http.*)/; ($k,$l,$m)=($1,$2,$3); $l=~s/[ *.#!]/\\$&/g; print "$k$l$m";' file
RewriteRule ^/trendy/the-reason-for-example http://www.example.com/trendy/the-reason [NC, L, R=301]
RewriteRule ^/lol/2015/10\.\.\._for-example http://www.example.com/lol/the-reason [NC, L, R=301]
RewriteRule ^/sports/this-one\*\*\*-as-well http://www.example.com/sports/this-one [NC, L, R=301]
RewriteRule ^/buzz/the-\#reason-for-buzz http://www.example.com/buzz/buzz-sells [NC, L, R=301]
RewriteRule ^/omg/\ what-the-hell http://www.example.com/omg/wthell [NC, L, R=301]
RewriteRule ^/hash/HELL-YEAH http://www.example.com/hash/oh-yes [NC, L, R=301]
RewriteRule ^/celeb/he-did-it\! http://www.example.com/celeb/we-believe [NC, L, R=301]
```

Comment: Are you escaping the space on first column? If yes then i don't need that part. I only need to escape those as mentioned in the desired result i mentioned. Also most edits need to happen on column 2...others need to be left as is..thanks!

Comment: @babababa OK, in that case, use the third approach. You can't use space to define the columns since you can also have spaces within them.

Comment: just tried the third approach but noticed you escaped the "^" in column one, but that needs to be left as well..thanks

Comment: @babababa oh, sorry, I wasn't escaping it, I was removing it. See the updated question.

Comment: looks good still looking at it very well..also can you edit the output of the third approach command for anyone else that may need it?..thanks..still looking to make sure all things are set

Comment: @babababa you're welcome. Sorry about not fixing the `^`s but I was on mobile and editing is a pain. All done now.

Answer (score 0):

Perl:

```
perl -pe '
  @f = split /\^|\s+http:/;
  $f[1] =~ s{([^\w/-])}{\\\\$1}g;
  $_ = $f[0] . "^" . $f[1] . " http:" . $f[2]
' file
```

```
RewriteRule ^/trendy/the-reason-for-example http://www.example.com/trendy/the-reason [NC, L, R=301]
RewriteRule ^/lol/2015/10\.\.\._for-example http://www.example.com/lol/the-reason [NC, L, R=301]
RewriteRule ^/sports/this-one\*\*\*-as-well http://www.example.com/sports/this-one [NC, L, R=301]
RewriteRule ^/buzz/the-\#reason-for-buzz http://www.example.com/buzz/buzz-sells [NC, L, R=301]
RewriteRule ^/omg/\ what-the-hell http://www.example.com/omg/wthell [NC, L, R=301]
RewriteRule ^/hash/HELL-YEAH http://www.example.com/hash/oh-yes [NC, L, R=301]
RewriteRule ^/celeb/he-did-it\! http://www.example.com/celeb/we-believe [NC, L, R=301]
```

Split the line on "^" or " http:", esacape all chars that are not alpha,numeric,underscore,slash,hyphen; then reform the line.

Comment: Hi glenn..i tried your answer but i don't want to escape the following characters (?, /)..i have edited my question to put those so it is clearer..thanks

Comment: Just add those chars (I already have "/") into the bracket expression. Make sure the hyphen is the last character inside the brackets.

Comment: did you edit the answer with right command? also i am not very good with perl and don't understand what each parts of the command does..explaining them will be greatly appreciated...thanks!

Comment: @terdon third approach worked..but will still like to see how your version works as well..really appreciate every second to help..thanks!!!